# how to make a screen transition using PysimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I would like to know how to make a screen transition using PysimpleGUI.

Specifically, I would like to be able to click a button at the top of the screen and have the screen corresponding to the button appear.
I have created the following code for this purpose.

When I click the button for the first time, the screen transitions (just reopen a new window) without any problem, but when I click the button for the second time, I get an error message like the one in the image.

[image]

How can I make it so that no matter how many times I press the tab button, I don't get the error message as shown in the image?
Also, is it possible to change only the layout in the same window like in a browser, instead of reopening a new window?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('メイリオ', 9))

#==========================================================================
### tab_button ###
tab1 = sg.Frame("",[[sg.Button("page1", key="-PAGE1-", size=(5, 1), disabled=True),  sg.Button("page2", key="-PAGE2-", size=(5, 1))]]),
tab2 = sg.Frame("",[[sg.Button("page1", key="-PAGE1-", size=(5, 1)),  sg.Button("page2", key="-PAGE2-", size=(5, 1), disabled=True)]])

frame1 = sg.Frame('',
        [
            [sg.Text("text1")], [sg.Input()],
            [sg.Text("text2")], [sg.Input()]
        ],
        size = (500, 600)
)

frame2 = sg.Frame('',
    [] , size=(500, 600)
)

#==========================================================================
def layout1():
    layout1 = [
            [tab1], 
            [frame1]
    ]
    return sg.Window("a", layout1, resizable=True, finalize=True)

def layout2():
    layout2 = [
            [tab2],
            [frame2] 
    ]
    return sg.Window("b", layout2, resizable=True, finalize=True)


#==========================================================================

window = layout1()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == '-PAGE1-':
        window.close()
        window = layout1()

    elif event == '-PAGE2-':
        window.close()
        window = layout2()

    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall not reuse layouts

It means that you have to initiate related elements when you create a new layout, not to use the elemenet already used in other layout, a new window means new layout, even they are in the same variable name.

revised code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def layout1():
    tab1 = sg.Frame("",[[sg.Button("page1", key="-PAGE1-", size=(5, 1), disabled=True),  sg.Button("page2", key="-PAGE2-", size=(5, 1))]]),
    frame1 = sg.Frame('',
            [
                [sg.Text("text1")], [sg.Input()],
                [sg.Text("text2")], [sg.Input()]
            ],
            size = (500, 600)
    )
    layout1 = [
            [tab1],
            [frame1]
    ]
    return sg.Window("a", layout1, resizable=True, finalize=True)

def layout2():
    tab2 = sg.Frame("",[[sg.Button("page1", key="-PAGE1-", size=(5, 1)),  sg.Button("page2", key="-PAGE2-", size=(5, 1), disabled=True)]])
    frame2 = sg.Frame('',
        [] , size=(500, 600)
    )
    layout2 = [
            [tab2],
            [frame2]
    ]
    return sg.Window("b", layout2, resizable=True, finalize=True)

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('メイリオ', 9))

window = layout1()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == '-PAGE1-':
        window.close()
        window = layout1()

    elif event == '-PAGE2-':
        window.close()
        window = layout2()

window.close()
```

To change only the layout in the same window, you can set option `visible` to be `True` or `False` to switch between different `Column` elements.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

now, pages = 0, 5

layout = [
    [sg.Button(f"Page {i+1}", key=("Page", i)) for i in range(pages)],
    [sg.Column(
        [[sg.Text(f"This is the page {i+1}", justification='center', expand_x=True, background_color="blue")]],
        pad=(0, 0),
        visible=(i==now),
        expand_x=True,
        key=("Column", i),
     ) for i in range(5)],
]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0]=="Page":
        window[("Column", now)].update(visible=False)
        now = event[1]
        window[("Column", now)].update(visible=True)

window.close()
```

If you insist to use the function to create your layout, maybe you can do like this one

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def column_layout(index):
    if index == 1:
        return [
            [sg.Text("text1")],
            [sg.Input(key=("Input", index, 1))],
            [sg.Text("text2")],
            [sg.Input(key=("Input", index, 2))],
        ]
    return []

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('メイリオ', 9))

layout = [
    [sg.Button("page1", key=("PAGE", 1), size=(5, 1), disabled=True),
     sg.Button("page2", key=("PAGE", 2), size=(5, 1))],
    [sg.Column(column_layout(1), visible=True,  pad=(0, 0), key=("COLUMN", 1), size=(240, 180)),
     sg.Column(column_layout(2), visible=False, pad=(0, 0), key=("COLUMN", 2), size=(240, 180))],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0] == 'PAGE':
        window[("PAGE", 1)].update(disabled=(event[1]==1))
        window[("PAGE", 2)].update(disabled=(event[1]==2))
        window[("COLUMN", 1)].update(visible=(event[1]==1))
        window[("COLUMN", 2)].update(visible=(event[1]==2))

window.close()
```

Anyway, you can choice which way is best for your GUI. The key point is how you program for your project if you feel it is good.

Comment: If I want to switch the contents of a window between showing and hiding the screen, is it not a good idea to make it a function as in my code?
I would like to see a program that switches between display and non-display with something similar to my code.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean !

Comment: Sorry, my native language is not English.
The second program you gave me is a program that runs to show and hide, no functions are used. In other words, if you have made it a function like my program, is it not possible to switch between display and non-display?
If it is possible, I would like the code to switch between display and non-display in my program.

Comment: You can call the function to return the layout, not the window, to the Column element in your main layout. Maybe work as the new third script.